# Get focus on Blender interface when working on a custom panel (pyside6 and Qt)

Tags: custom-attributes

I created an Animation Picker panel using pyside6 and Qt, and so far, everything is going pretty well. However, the Picker has a feature which allows the user to click on a button and immediately control a bone without the necessity of 'selecting' the Blender interface first; its implementation looks like the following code:

```
import win32gui

window_name = "Blender"
window_handle = win32gui.FindWindow(None, window_name)
win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(window_handle)
```

However, the Picker sometimes focuses on the Blender Toggle Console instead of its interface. Anyone who has worked with pyside6 and Qt? Thank you very much in advance.